# How to evaluate effectiveness of a Dapp

Tags: dapp-development, dapps

I am developing a private **ethereum-based DApp** and writing an academic paper for a final year project. I'm trying to **"blockchainify"** an existing system that adopts a traditional client-server approach.

The goal of the study is to **prove the feasibility of a blockchain solution** as an alternative platform from that of a traditional web application. The goal **is not about** is to prove that blockchain is more effective or ineffective than the traditional approach. So this is more of an exploratory research.

Regardless of the usecase, and the application that I am trying to build. What are some **measurable** functional or performance **metrics** that I can use to possibly compare my DApp to the other one. **Security** for example is a descriptive parameter which is almost always associated with DApp, but **effectiveness** is a broad word, and I would want to provide some measurable metrics to evaluate whether a DApp is effective or not.

Assuming that every functionality is implemented and **works exactly** in the Dapp as is in the original application, what are some measurable **performance metrics** that can be used to evaluate effectiveness or ineffectiveness of a Decentralized App?

ps. if the question is too broad, and if it helps, I can provide specific context.

Comment: I'd say it's very difficult to compare them side by side in numbers as they reside in completely different worlds.

Comment: I guess what I was trying to say is... I saw this article https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-1-40d2d0d807c2 it's a voting app. Ideally you would market that this app is 'more secure' than traditional electronic voting systems, which should be an already proven attribute given the cryptographic nature of the blockchain. However, I must ask the question as to why or why would you not use a blockchain voting application.

Comment: Well, then please reword your question to not ask about numerical metrics but about the generic reasons to use dapp instead of 'traditional' app

Answer (score 0):

One of the problem that blockchain is facing is **scalability**. One of the metrics that you should focus on is **TPS**(Transactions Per Second). A lot of extensive research is going on improving in improving the number of transactions that can be validated by the participating nodes in the blockchain.